# Passenger, Nginx, and Capistrano - Passenger not launching Rails app at all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, passenger, capistrano

Essentially, my route is working perfectly, Passenger seems to be loading - all is hunky-dory. Except that nothing Railsy happens. Here's my Nginx log from starting the server to the first request (ignore the different domain/route - it's because I haven't moved the new domain over yet, and it's returning a 403 error because there's no index file in the public folder):

```
[ pid=24559 file=ext/nginx/HelperServer.cpp:826 time=2009-11-10 00:49:13.227 ]:
  Passenger helper server started on PID 24559
[ pid=24559 file=ext/nginx/HelperServer.cpp:831 time=2009-11-10 00:49:13.227 ]:
  Password received.
2009/11/10 00:49:53 [error] 24578#0: *1 directory index of "/var/www/***/current/public/" is forbidden, client: 188.221.195.27, server: ***, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "***"
2009/11/10 00:49:54 [error] 24578#0: *1 open() "/var/www/***/current/public/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 188.221.195.27, server: ***, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "***", referrer: "***"
```

Someone on the RubyOnRails IRC channel suggested that it might be a webserver permissions problem. I had a suspicion that it might be a filesystem permission problem, but then Nginx runs as www-data and Passenger as root.

I can load static files from within the public directory fine, but no Rails application is being launched. Does anyone have an idea? My head is gradually melting away figuring this one out!

Edit: Here's the vhost file:

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  ***;
        passenger_enabled on;

        location / {
            root   /var/www/***/current/public;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check your logs. They may provide you with some more clues.

Comment: Which logs? The logs in the question are my Nginx ones which Passenger is set to write to, are there any others around I should check? :)

Comment: Who owns the directory at /var/www/imayges.co.uk?

Comment: Don't run Passenger as root. If someone gains control of it, they have root access to your system.

Comment: You should post your vhost file as well. There could be a problem with that. But your post does say forbidden, I'd be surprised if this wasn't some kind of permissions issue, what else could cause it to be forbidden.

Comment: Passenger will never run as root.  It is designed to in no way ever run an application as root.
http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#user_switching

Comment: The forbidden element of the log is just because directory listing is turned off, it accesses static files fine. I meant that the Passenger process is running as root, but thanks for that link danivo - I didn't know about the user switching. I have a feeling permissions may be the key - I'm gonna try opening up SSH for the www-data user and upload it that way, as chown doesn't seem to be doing much.

Comment: Added the vhost file. Also, I tried removing the app, switching to the www-data user and generating a new one in rails. It finds the rails welcome page in the public folder, but doesn't load the Rails app itself. Now that really should have worked, what the hell is going on? :|

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem solved, I am a spanner.

I had 'passenger_enabled on;' inside 'location /' not 'server'. I hereby hand in my coding hands.